# SwiftUI platform testing deuglification (composing view hierarchies)

Tags: swiftui, preprocessor

I could use a way or two to make this not as ugly moving the filler for HStack/List into a common helper method or make a helper for wrapper of the ForEach to prebuild a portion of a view hierarchy somehow?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      if horizontalScroll {
        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
          HStack {
            ForEach(videos) { video in
              Button {
                selectedVideo = video
              } label: {
                VideoRow(video: video)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        List {
          //        makeEmbeddedVideoPlayer()
          ForEach(videos) { video in
            Button {
              selectedVideo = video
            } label: {
              VideoRow(video: video)
            }
          }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Travel Vlogs")
      }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedVideo) {
      embeddedVideoRate = 1.0
    } content: { item in
      makeFullScreenVideoPlayer(for: item)
    }
  }


var horizontalScroll: Bool {
#if os(tvOS)
    return true
#else
    return false
#endif
  }
```

A naive attempt to make a common helper yielded this

[image]

What's the return type for the guts of List/Hstack?

Comment: good on you mate, go for it.

Comment: Well, that was not a statement that was a question to the swiftly UI inclined and versed. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Use `some View` instead of `Content`, just like in `body`.

Comment: That worked. Care to write that as an answer?